# Bolding of answers icon (when correct answer present) indents title in question list

Tags: bug

Minor layout bug, seen in FireFox (currently latest version 54.0.1) under Windows (independent of browser width)

When the *# answers* icon is bold because there is a correct answer, the views counter and question title get indented a few pixels:

[image]

[image]

---

In addition, here is a specific case where *answer* vs. *answers* also shows alignment issues:

[image]

Comment: Might be Firefox-only - I don't see it in Chrome, on Linux or Windows.

Comment: It's a result of the fonts selected and the way they are rendered. Using Firefox on Linux, by overriding the font selection I can make it better, or worse. With default setting, and without knowing which fonts are actually used by each, I get the following results; Chrome- 4 pixel shift, Firefox- 5 pixel shift, and Konquerer- No shift (although the bold "answers" is still slightly longer, 3 pixels, than the regular weight version). If I force Firefox to use Courier 10 for all fonts, then the "answer" and "answers" without bold are not aligned, and the bold "answers" is even farther misaligned.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver and for others reading along: I have Win7 with default fonts; no extra fonts were ever installed.

Comment: It looks like they designed the center column "answers" slightly to tight. Each browser, on each system will find its _preferred_ fonts to use to satisfy the CSS font selections. My experiments only confirm your problem, and help isolate the cause, if and when the developers choose to fix it. Because it's such a small deviation, I suspect it'll be an ultra-low priority to correct it. Still, a good catch and a valid report.